# xrandr (intel driver, igpu) not recognizing config file or any unconnected screens (DVI, Virtual, etc)

Tags: drivers, xorg, xrandr, gpu, xorg.conf

I was trying to setup a virtual display on my 610 igpu minipc.  I have tried to edit 20-intel.conf files (had to create) in both /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d (where other manufacturer config files existed) and /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d.

to add:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intelgpu0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "VirtualHeads" "1"
EndSection
```

However, I'm not convinced something between the minipc and driver is even looking for the file.  as my xrandr output ignores all other outputs:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080     59.96*+
1440x1080     59.99  
(followed by a lot more resolutions) but nothing at the bottom
```

But there is no VIRTUAL1 or even DVI.  I'm using DP, and even that just shows up as SCREEN 0.

It looks like the driver is correctly loaded and recognizes the 610?

```
$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 610 (WHL GT1) (0x3ea1)
Version: 22.2.5
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 7795MB
Unified memory: yes
Preferred profile: core (0x1)
Max core profile version: 4.6
Max compat profile version: 4.6
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
```

Pretty noobie, any assistance on next steps greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth in case others find this I ended up using nx protocol from NoMachine.

My questioned was uninformed, as I was reviewing too old of ubuntu posts, and the details were relevant to X11 and not necessarily to Wayland.

There is a cool secondary screen feature to use a virtual screen with Wayland to extend your desktop:
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.remote-desktop.rdp screen-share-mode extend

and to turn it off you change the flag from extend to mirror-primary.

Ultimately, headless VNC seemed risky and not yet implemented. I did get RD working, but unfortunately the only real iphone app for that is Microsoft's Remote Desktop Mobile, and there were screen resolution and scaling issues.